# Bloomberg European equities tickers

Tags: equities, bloomberg

I am trying to understand the abbreviations in the Bloomberg European stock or STOXX data. Each ticker represents **company name abbreviation - Listed exchange**.

For example, CSP - LN is Countryside Properties PLC - **London stock exchange**. I am hoping to find a document where I can get the **"two-letter"** abbreviation used for all the European stock exchanges - can please someone guide me on this?

**Comment** The out of date document (see the first comment by @noob2) had all the exchange codes for the recent STOXX 600 except 'SE', which stands for the Swiss Stock Exchange.

Comment: The most recent Exchange Codes can be found with the EPRX {go} command. A slightly out of date list can be found online here https://guides.library.cornell.edu/ld.php?content_id=18933264 . Note that there can be both a specific code for an exchange (UN =  NYSE exchange) and a Composite Code that covers multiple exchanges in a country (eg, US = any US exchange including but not limited to NYSE).

Comment: I don't have access to the Bloomberg, so I guess I have to settle for the link you gave. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

May I refer you to [my own list](https://github.com/ga-group/bsym/blob/master/pricing_source.ttl).

Bloomberg used to make this available in pre-OpenFIGI times (when the service was called bsym).  Nowadays, apart from the OMG FIGI specification, it's nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 0):

See this. "International Exchanges" section
https://www.quotemedia.com/quotetools/symbolHelp/SymbolHelp_US_Version_Default.html

Comment: This is a good start, but these aren't (all) the symbols that Bloomberg uses. I don't see Bogota (CB) or Toronto (CN) or Moscow, for example. Also Bloomberg uses BZ for Brazil, not BV.